# How can I make a previously incremented set of numbers appear below the current numbers in a new line?

Tags: javascript, html, function, setinterval, timertask

I wrote a javascript that increases a set of numbers every second, where every increased set writes on a new line separated by a horizontal rule. E.g;

20220215155

20220215156

20220215157

20220215158 etc...

```
var i = 20220215155;
    function increment(){
     i++;
        document.getElementById('period').innerHTML += i + "<br />" + "<hr />" ;
    }
    setInterval('increment()', 1000);
```

But I want every current set of the numbers to always be in the first line, whereby a previously increased set goes below the currently increased set... E.g;

20220215159

20220215158

20220215157

20220215156

20220215155

Please how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```html
<button id="start">Start Incrementing</button>
<button id="stop">Stop Incrementing</button>
<div id="main"></div>

<script>
    const main = document.querySelector('#main');
    const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
    const stopBtn = document.querySelector('#stop');
    let i = 0;
    let interval = null;

    const createElem = () => {
        const div = document.createElement('p');
        div.className = 'inc-elem';
        const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        h1.innerText = i;
        const hr = document.createElement('hr');

        div.appendChild(h1);
        div.appendChild(hr);
        return div;
    };

    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const startingDiv = createElem();
        main.prepend(startingDiv);
    });

    const increment = () => {
        i++;
        const newDiv = createElem();
        main.prepend(newDiv);
    };

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => (interval = setInterval(increment, 1000)));
    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', () => clearInterval(interval));
</script>
```